# yii1 CActiveForm numberfield does not accept decimal values

Tags: php, forms, yii, yii1.x

I need to create a CActiveForm that allows decimal values to be entered into a numberField.

The model rules include setting that attribute's integerOnly value to false, but it seems like the problem is with the form, not the model's validation rules. When I try to submit the form with a decimal value, it tells me to enter a valid value.

The message depends on the browser that I'm using. Safari says, "Enter a valid value." Chrome says, "Please enter a valid value. The two nearest valid values are x and y." where x and y are the two closest integers to what I input.

Has anybody experienced this or does anyone know how to correct it?

Following is code similar to what I have:

**FORM**

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'action' => Yii::app()->createUrl('person/create', array(
                'school' => $school->id
        )),
        'method' => 'get',
        'htmlOptions' => array(
                'class' => 'generic-form'
        )
)); ?>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="left field-container one-fourth">
                        <?= $form->label($person, 'name') ?>
                        <?= $form->textField($person, 'name') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="left field-container one-fourth">
                        <?= $form->label($person, 'height') ?>
                        <?= $form->numberField($person, 'height') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="left field-container one-fourth">
                        <?= $form->label($person, 'age') ?>
                        <?= $form->numberField($person, 'age') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="left one-fourth">
                        <?= TbHtml::submitButton('', array(
                                'id' => 'submit-create-person',
                                'class' => 'fa fa-plus generic-button'
                        )); ?>
                </div>
        </div>
<?php $this->endWidget() ?>
```

**MODEL**

```
public function rules()
{
        return array(
                array('school_id', 'required'),
                array('name', 'safe'),
                array('height', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => false),
                array('age', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use textField instead of numberField for validation in your form.

**Form**

```
<div class="left field-container one-fourth">
     <?= $form->label($person, 'height') ?>
     <?= $form->textField($person, 'height') ?>
</div>
```

You get different validation errors on the different browser because of your number input type. All browser has its own validation. you can check by inspect element `numberField` is number input type.

If you have Yii 1.1.7 or up version then you can use [enableClientValidation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator#enableClientValidation-detail) to true or false this will disable your browser validation.

Check your Yii version `echo Yii::getVersion();`